# Upload is stripping image metadata MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, post

I have a simple file upload that is for adding images to a record in our business app. The issue is that after the file is uploaded and I am in my C# controller I do not have the EXIF data for the image. I am not doing anything special just:

HTML

```
<form action="/Image/Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" class="form-control" style="width:80%" name="photo" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
            <input type="hidden" name="clientid" id="hvClientid" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" value="Upload"/>
        </form>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase photo, FormCollection items)
    {

        string clientId = items[0].ToString();

        var tempimg = Image.FromStream(photo.InputStream);
        if (ImageTools.DetermineIfImageSizeAboveMax(tempimg))
            tempimg = ImageTools.Resize(tempimg, ImageTools.ImageSize.Large);

        var exif = new EXIF();
        var img = exif.FixOrientation(tempimg);

        var azure = new Azure.Blob.Consumer.StorageConsumer(clientId, Azure.StorageBase.MyApp);
        var tempUri = azure.CacheImage(img, photo.FileName);

        return Json(new { path = tempUri });
    }
```

The tempimg variable does not contain all the EXIF metadata that is present on the original file. The EXIF class is just a lib i wrote to do things like fix orientation etc.

Comment: before you ask I can go to an online exif viewer and see all fields I need.

Comment: I'm guessing that ImageTools is stripping the EXIF data.

Comment: @DavidCrowell that method is not even hit yet

Answer (score 0):

Fetching Attributes from the azure storage before setting the properties might help you retain the exif data while uploading the image.

```
CloudBlockBlob blob = sampleContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(photo.FileName);
blob.FetchAttributes();
blob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpg";
blob.SetProperties();
```

Also make sure that the image contain's necessary *Exif* data before its uploading.
(In my case I was sending the image through a chat app which actually removed the Exif data from the image.)
please refer [this blog](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/cloud-data/an-introduction-to-windows-azure-blob-storage-/) for more info